# Showing the Birthdate in Magento Order-Mail

Tags: php, email, magento

I would like to show the Birthday of a customer in their order-mail. In the registration mail it is

> {{var customer.dob}}

But this doesn't work in the Order-Mail. Also:

> {{var order.getCustomerDob()}}

doesn't work. And I cannot find the right syntax online. Do you have a clue? Or do I need to write an extra method for that, and if so, where?

Comment: Hmm, have you tried something like `{{var order.getCustomer().dob}}`?

Comment: Tried it, but that doesn't work

Comment: can you please post the answer to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$customers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')  
  ->getCollection()  
  ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')  
  ->addAttributeToSelect('lastname')  
  ->addAttributeToFilter('dob',array('like'=>'%-'.date('m-d').' %'))  
  ->load();
```

Comment: That probably works for a programmatically solution. But I need it diretly in the E-Mail template. I thought, that there is some kind of template-solution for this.

Comment: Then, use the following link [Email Templates](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-advanced-transactional-email-templates)